# Trouble with wpp_get_mostpopular(), function not processing arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to have my most popular posts appear in a custom  format. Below is the code:

```
    <div class="mostviewed">
            <h1>HOTTEST STORIES</h1>
            <?php
                $popular = array(
                  'header_start' =>  '',
                  'header' => '',
                  'header_end' => '',
                  'range' => 'daily',
                  'limit' => 4,
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                    'wpp_start' => '<ul>',
                    'wpp_end' => '</ul>',
                    'post_html' => '<li><a href=\"{url}\">{thumb}</a><p>{text_title}</p></li>');
               wpp_get_mostpopular($popular);
            ?>
        </div>
```

However when I run the script wpp_get_mostpopular() doesn't recognize any of my parameters, and I get a default output.